# Mysql: expanding a selection including missing records from the original table

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table **items** with four elements

```
| item_id | description | ... | ... |
|---------|-------------|-----|-----|
|       1 | foo         | ... | ... |
|       2 | bar         | ... | ... |
|       3 | biz         | ... | ... |
|       4 | boo         | ... | ... |
```

and a **SELECT** query, let's call it ***the query***, that returns something like that:

```
| item_id | inventory |
|---------|-----------|
|       2 |        123|        
|       3 |        456|
```

**inventory** is not a field of the **items** table but the result of some calculations inside ***the query***.

As the example shows, not all the records in **items** are returned (this is expected).

I'd like to "expand" the selection including all missing records from **items** with their **id** and **inventory** set to 0.

Like this

```
| item_id | inventory |
|---------|-----------|
|       2 |        123|        
|       3 |        456|
|       1 |          0|        
|       4 |          0|
```

I've tried

```
SELECT    #### "the query" here ####
UNION
SELECT `item_id`, 0 AS `inventory` from `items`
```

But I get duplicate items.

Like this

```
| item_id | inventory |
|---------|-----------|
|       2 |        123|        
|       3 |        456|
|       1 |          0|        
|       2 |          0|
|       3 |          0|        
|       4 |          0|
```

I'm looking for a way to do that *without* modifying ***the query*** but rather "expanding" the selection.

Comment: Post the original query, and a simple LEFT join helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT i.item_id, coalesce(q.inventory, 0) as inventory
from items i left outer join
     (   #### "the query" here ####
     ) q
     on q.item_id = i.item_id;
```